# Comparing two objects in Java with compare function

Tags: java

I have a class with the signature

```
public class MyLinkedList<E extends Comparable <? super E>> extends AbstractList<E>
```

and inside I have an `ArrayList<E>` object.

However I'm getting an error when I do

```
if(arr.get(i).compareTo(arr.get(j))>0)
```

The error is that it seems to not be able to compare a non-E type. After a while the error somehow disappeared but my code still isn't working.

<strike>I see no point in putting up my whole code because I think it's the compareTo that is the problem.</strike>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a check on the size of array first before bubbling it up to avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
private void bubbleUp(int index) 
{
    if(index != 0 && arr.size()>index){...}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need to do this:

```
if(arr.get(i).compareTo(arr.get(j))>0)
```

Observe the closing bracket after the compareTo argument

Comment: You're right. Sadly, there's an option to vote to close for typo problems.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a bug, but it still doesn't work. I will go ahead and fix the post.

Comment: The question typo was fixed. This answer became invalid =\

Comment: @user3511965 Have you overridden the compareTo method ?

Comment: I tested Integer a = new Integer(5);
Integer b = new Integer(6);
System.out.println(a.compareTo(b)); and it returns me -1, do I have to do it for my case at all? (I will be using Integer too...)

Comment: *Have you overridden the compareTo method?* Re-read the question: `MyLinkedList<E extends Comparable <? super E>>` which posses attribute `ArrayList<E> arr = new ArrayList<E>`, which means every element in `arr` already implements `Comparable` interface.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Ah I see. But wouldn't that be inheriting the compareTo method which means there is no need to override it?

Comment: @user3511965 that's correct. That means your code is fine, and your problem cannot be understood by your current context. Please post the relevant code (a [sscce](http://sscce.org) where this problem arises.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza On your second comment, are questions always taken at face value? SO should give posters the opportunity to correct trivial mistakes...

Comment: @user3511965 I don't understand what do you mean by your last comment. I do even upvoted your question since I saw an invalid (IMO) downvote. And the only thing I'm asking here is for you to **post the necessary code to replicate the problem, spot the issue and notify it back to you**. Currently, you're going to a doctor and saying *I have a headache, give me medicine*, we ask you for symptoms and you keep saying *I have headache, don't you understand?*, so there are dozens of medicines that may help you but we cannot provide none until know your exact problem.

Comment: @JunedAhsan Huzzah. Code added. Maybe you could help too?